# Finding the maximum sum of any 2 elements in an array of integers

Tags: java, array

this no-brainer came up to me in a technical interview. I played it safe and wrote this.

```
 public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter size of the array: ");

    if (!in.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("put an integer! ");
    }
    int size = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("enter numbers for array");

    int[] array = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    maxSum(array);

    System.out.println(maxSum(array));
  }

  private static int maxSum(int[] array) {

    int max = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {

        int currentMax = array[i] + array[j];

        if (currentMax > max) {
          max = currentMax;
        }
      }
    }

    return max;
  }
}
```

obviously O(n^2) is not the best approach but I just wanted to finish the question without spending to much time, what do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code tries all \$ n (n+1)/2 \$ combinations of array elements to find the
combination with the largest sum, so the complexity is \$ O(n^2) \$.

A better solution would be to find the two largest elements in the
array, since adding those obviously gives the largest sum.

Possible approaches are:

- *Sort* the array elements in increasing order and add the last two
  elements. Efficient sorting algorithms (such as Quicksort) have an
  average complexity of \$ O(n \log(n)) \$.
- Traverse the array once and keep track of the largest and second
  largest element encountered so far. Then add those elements.
  The complexity is \$ O(n) \$.

Other remarks:

- Your main program computes `maxSum(array)` twice,
  which is not necessary.
- You should check if the user entered at least 2 elements, otherwise
  the problem is ill-defined.
- The `if (!in.hasNextInt())` check is not really helpful. If the user
  enters a non-integer, "put an integer! " is printed, but then `in.nextInt()` fails with an exception. You could for example
  skip the entire input line until a valid integer is entered:

  ```
  while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer! ");
      in.nextLine();
  }
  int size = in.nextInt();
  ```

Comment: With the second suggested approach being the most obvious =)

Answer (score 1):

#### Overflow issues

If the largest two integers added together exceed the maximum integer value, you will not come up with the correct answer.  For example, 2000000000 + 2000000000 becomes some negative value and you would miss that as the answer.  To do this correctly you should do the addition using `long` and store the max value in a `long` as well:

```
    long currentMax = (long) array[i] + (long) array[j];
```

Even if you used the better algorithm of finding the two largest values in the array, you would still need to return a `long` in order to return the correct sum.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `i < array.length - 1;`  because `j = i + 1;`

This can be done in one pass.  Just have an array of 2 that you save the biggest 2.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context around this answer?

Comment: @StephenRauch That is the only thing I saw.

Comment: I wasn't asking for you to make more points, I was just hoping for some explanation of these two points.  You have added some more on the second point, which helps, but the first remains unexplained.  Thanks.

Comment: @StephenRauch j = i + 1